# Php turn decimal string into decimal, but keep trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, string, highcharts

I need to turn my string decimals into decimals to use with highcharts API.

I need to keep my trailing zeros so I have a string like this "0.00030900" and I turn it into the exact same thing without the quotes 0.00030900

I need it to stay exactly the same format so that way it looks correct when I return it to the screen.

I know  0.00030900 is the same as 0.000309  mathematically but visually they are not the same and I need them to look visually the same.

I've tried floatval() that strips it off my zeros. I've tried multiplying my strings by 1 and then using number_format() to add my zeros back but number_format turns my decimal back into a string.

Comment: I don't know highcharts, but can it not take a number for the data and a string for a label?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Well it uses the data for the label.  See this example when you start hovering over the chart it pulls up the data points and also uses the data points on the xAxis https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: @Calimero why the Js tag, while the title clearly says Php?

Comment: @nl-x see my answer. Been there, done that, reformatting in php is useless in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the highcharts formatter callback feature to achieve this since that format is nonstandard.

Note that is has nothing to do with php whatsoever. You just provide your values to highcharts as plain floating-point values and reformat them there for display as necesary (otherwise you'll either waste your time or run into problems in your graph, such as values not being ordered properly).

A few such properties in highcharts are :

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

In any case, your callback function would have to get the floating-point number value, convert it to a string, and pad any number of zeroes to the right until it is the right length.